# How to get QASM code from IBMQ experience

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I am interested in retrieving the OpenQasm code of a quantum circuit, as it appears on IBM Quantum Experience. This is the code that the quantum machine actually runs. I used to be able to just copy the code from the results tab, but I seem to not be able to do that anymore. Is there any way to retrieve said Qasm code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the results tab, above the circuit diagram, there is an option to see the QASM code
[image]

**[EDIT]** You cannot copy and paste code from this tab. You can retrieve the QASM in a text format simply by using Qiskit instead, all you need is the Job ID. This code can be run easily in a notebook in the IBM Quantum Experience. You can do this as follows

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
result = backend.retrieve_job('job id')
qob = result.qobj()

from qiskit.assembler import disassemble
jobs = disassemble(qob)
qc = jobs[0][0]

qc.qasm()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I know there is the option, but I want to get the QASM code, not just look at it. Like, I used to be able to just select it and copy-paste it, now I cannot anymore.

Comment: I see what you mean, that is really weird! It can be done quite simply using Qiskit, which you can run in a notebook on the IBM Quantum Experience, all you need is the job ID. I have updated my answer to show how this can be done.